# Wordpress Customizer sanitize_callback: How to Reset to Default on Fail

Tags: wordpress

I check the sanity of some settings with `sanitize_callback`. It works, but on fail, I want to reset the value do the default one. How can I do that?

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    $attribute[0],
    array(
        "default" => $attribute[1],
        "sanitize_callback" => $validate_func,
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `sanitize_callback` is not meant for validation, it simply cleans the input for return. If you post your `$validate_func` we might be able to help a little more.

**EDIT** Perhaps if you set your function to `return false` on fail it might help?

As always, the Codex is not a bad place to look. (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_setting)

Comment: What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: The `sanitize_callback` option that is part of Add-Setting is only meant for, surprisingly, sanitation. This function will allow only what you set the function to allow through or nothing at all. For example the `esc_html()` function. Have you tried telling your `validate_func()` to return `$attribute[1]`?